# Ionic's 'capacitor update' doesn't pull PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION variable form config.xml

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, google-play-services, cordova-plugins, capacitor

That's about it. I was having trouble because version 11.8.0 of Google Services was crashing my cordova-plugin-googleplus when doing authentication. When I update it to 16.0.1 in gradle configs, it works, but I have to rewrite it manually every build, because cap sync rewrites it back to 11.8.0.

I altered the PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION variable from 11.8.0 to 16.0.0 in config.xml and package.json at Ionic's root directory, but it stills rewrites it back to 11.8.0 in every build. Where should I change this version so I don't get this annoyance?

Answer (score 0):

Capacitor doesn't read the config.xml

If you want to force a version just add that library in the dependencies section of the app's build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:16.0.0'
```

that should force that version

Comment: Yeah, but gradle files are overwritten everytime I do `capacitor upgrade` command. Where does it pull the version from?

Comment: No, the app's build.gradle is not overwritten and it's the one that takes precedence when the other files have different versions

Comment: But I'm changing it everytime I build it to test or deploy, otherwise my app won't work, and I have to change the gradle files everytime I use `capacitor upgrade`. Maybe Ionic does it, but I don't know where it's pulling 11.8.0 from.

Comment: There are a lot of gradle files and you are probably not doing it in the app’s build.gradle. That’s the main one and the only one that doesn’t get overwritten

Comment: @jcesarmobile I know this is an old question, but I'm having this issue myself and overriding this at the app level still produces"com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1 in the capacitor.build.gradle wich results in a build error.

playServicesLocationVersion is on 17.0 (variables.gradle)